# Add <h1> text to right of logo in rwd for large layout only

Tags: rwd

I'm talking about the "Madison Island" graphic in the top left: http://enterprise-demo.user.magentotrial.com/. I just want a slogan where the white space is, and it doesn't need to be in the small layout. I tried adding

```
<div class="large">
  <h1>My Cool Site</h1>
</div>
```

to **app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/page/html/header.phtml** but that showed it in all layouts.

Comment: i can't understand

Comment: header.phtml uses in add the layout file. what you want only the home page it show?

Comment: By "large layout" are you referring to only show it on desktop (not mobile or tablets)?

Comment: I use the term "large" because I can see there are two modes used in the file mentioned, header.phtml, when displaying the logo. I just took the term from them, they appear already as class="large" and class="small". This must be the way the layout switches from mobile to desktop, so what I'm saying is i want the text when we are in desktop mode only - the one referred to in that file as "large". Thanks.